# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "The index was out of range of the array." c# ReadWriteMemory

Tags: c#, arrays

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "The index was out of range of the array."
```

I tried to make a menu, that can spawn weapons using `Read/WriteMemory` in C#

Unfortunately I got this error message:

```
The index was out of range of the array
```

Can somebody help me?

Here is the source code:

```
private void WeaponPistol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uint vIn = 0xA2719263;
    long vOut = Convert.ToInt64(vIn);

    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(
        "00004D48-FiveM_GTAProcess.exe")[0];
    IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(
         PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, process.Id);

    int bytesWritten = 0;
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("WEAPON_PISTOL\0"); 
    WriteProcessMemory((int) processHandle, (int)vOut , buffer, 
        buffer.Length, ref bytesWritten);
}
```

I tried everything but I can't find anything. I'm getting following error message:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(
           "00004D48-FiveM_GTAProcess.exe")[0]; line
```

Comment: If you get the error on the indicated line, all the rest of your question is irrelevant and only confusing, What is the result of `Process.GetProcessesByName("00004D48-FiveM_GTAProcess.exe")`?

Comment: What do you mean by result?

Comment: `GetProcessesByName` returns an array. Have you inspected that array in the debugger? I suspect it's empty.

Comment: `Process.GetProcessesByName` returns an array. It can be empty. `Process.GetProcessesByName("00004D48-FiveM_GTAProcess.exe")[0];` assumes it is not, but because it is you're accessing it out of range.

Comment: Aside from anything else, I suspect you shouldn't have `.exe` at the end. From the documentation: "The process name is a friendly name for the process, such as Outlook, that does not include the .exe extension or the path."